# Wordpress wpdb update not working

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

```
$wsquery = array( 'faculty_id' => $uid);
$tid = array('id'=>1);
$tname = 'imtd_faculty_in_focus';
$wpdb->update( $tname, $wsquery , $tid);
```

This is my update code;
But evertime it returns **Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on null**

all values are set.

Comment: According to the error -$wpdb is undefined. In case you put this code in a function, make sure to add `global $wpdb;` before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on null

According to the error -$wpdb is undefined.

My guess is that you're using this code in a function.
If this is the case, you should add the following line in order to use this class in your function:

```
global $wpdb;
```

So your code should look like:

```
function anon_function($uid) {
 global $wpdb;

 $wsquery = array( 'faculty_id' => $uid);
 $tid = array('id'=>1);
 $tname = 'imtd_faculty_in_focus';
 $wpdb->update( $tname, $wsquery , $tid);
}
```